# Executing Javascript on a webpage with python requests

Tags: python, encryption, python-requests

I am not sure if this is possible but let me try to explain.

I am trying to post data from a form but before my data gets posted the website encrypts some of it, with a public key, that i am able to achieve from the response.text

I found the javascript that is used

```
var myVal = 123                  
n = (myVal, ClassName.create(publicKey);
n.encrypt(myVal)
```

The .encrypt returns the string that is passed to the form.  My question is can I somehow bring that javascript into my script so I can execute that .encrypt method to pass that properly to the form?

Comment: maybe you can look in the js code what type of encryption used, and use the method of encryption yourself.

Comment: Yea its a bit complex. and spread through multiple methods. I guess this would help. javascript function test(val){ alert(val)}

request(url)
call the test(val) function thats on that "url" page

Answer (score -1):

if the script is simple,I will use `pyexecjs`

```
import execjs
js_cmd = '''
function add(x,y){
   return x+y
}
'''
cxt = execjs.compile(js_cmd)
print(cxt.eval("add(3,4)"))
```